# Rails 4: Scope for empty dependent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, scopes

I have a `Client` model that `has_many :weigh_ins` and I want to write a scope that pulls all clients **without** any weigh ins.

**How do I write that query?**

Answer (score 1):

`Client.includes(:weigh_ins).where(weigh_ins: {client_id: nil})`

This will do a left outer join between `clients` and `weigh_ins`, and then select only `Client` records where there is no `WeighIn` with that `client_id`.